# R - tapply column mean, returning logical array

Tags: r, tapply

I have a data frame.

I am trying to use the `tapply` function to find the average of one column when the values of a second column are equal to a given value.

I want `tapply` to return the value of the mean, but it is returning a logical array

(FALSE - the mean when the values of second column do not equal to the given value, and TRUE - the mean when the  values of the second column do equal the given value)

This is the function I am applying (I want the mean of column "hp" when column "cyl" is equal to 4)

```
tapply(mtcars$hp,mtcars$cyl==4,mean)
```

This is what is being returned:

```
 FALSE      TRUE 
180.23810  82.63636
```

How can I get the output to simply be 82.63636?

Thank you

Comment: grab the 2nd element of the result `tapply(mtcars$hp,mtcars$cyl==4,mean)[[2]]`

Comment: Awesome, definitely worked. Thank you!

Comment: Although, do you need `tapply` at all? `mean(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4, "hp"])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **have** to use `tapply`, you need to subset the result to only return the value you want

```
tapply(mtcars$hp,mtcars$cyl==4,mean)[[2]]
82.63636
```

However, to get the mean of a column, subset by another colum, you can just call `mean` on the subsetted data

```
mean(mtcars$hp[mtcars$cyl == 4])
82.63636

## similarly
# mean(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4, "hp"])
```